# SQL - TOP , IN ,WHERE , AND

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote a sentence like that :

```
"SELECT TOP 4 Words1, Words2, Type, ID FROM Table1 WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3 ) AND Type IN (4 )"
```

It works well for me

Then I tried something like that:

```
"SELECT TOP 4 Words1, Words2, Type, ID FROM Table1 WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3 ) AND Type IN (4 ) WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT TOP 4 ID FROM Table1 WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3 ) AND Type IN (4 ) )"
```

I try not to take the first 4 rows,
 I couldn't write the syntax for that

any suggestions how to fix? thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you looking for this? `select * from table
except
select top 4 * from table`

Comment: @viveknuna I tried to replace  "WHERE ID NOT IN"  with except , didnt work ..

Comment: Looks like you have the `where` keyword twice in your main query. Change the second one to `and`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the ORDER BY:

```sql
SELECT TOP 4 
    Words1, 
    Words2, 
    Type, 
    ID 
FROM 
    Table1 
WHERE 
    Unit IN (1, 2, 3) 
    AND 
    Type IN (4) 
    AND
    ID NOT IN 
        (SELECT TOP 4 ID 
        FROM Table1 
        WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3) AND Type IN (4)
        ORDER BY ID DESC)
ORDER BY 
    ID DESC
```

Comment: wow , its work , tnx man , I tried this but I used only one time ORDER BY ID , I ignored the second :D

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I tried to do another similar one and it didn't work .. Thanks for the help.  SELECT Words1,Words2, Type, ID FROM Table1 WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3 ) AND Type IN (4 ) AND TypeAB IN (2  ) ORDER BY ID

Comment: The criteria should be same in the main query as in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, use `OFFSET`/`FETCH`:

```
SELECT Words1, Words2, Type, ID
FROM Table1
WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3 ) AND Type IN (4 )
OFFSET 4 FETCH FIRST 4 ROWS ONLY;
```

You would use `OFFSET 0` to start at the first row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 4 Words1, Words2, Type, ID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3 ) 
AND Type IN (4 )
AND ID NOT IN ( 
SELECT TOP 4 ID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3 ) AND Type IN (4 )
 )
```

I think you just an error in using WHERE a second time instead of AND in your main clause. Although this will run without an error, you should include an ORDER BY when you use TOP. It makes what you're trying to do clearer. My guess is you're basing this on ID. You can get away with that in Access since it is probably the Primary Key, so it's used by default. It's also nice to understand what problem you're trying to solve. SQL statements don't always show intent.

Comment: thank for you answer , I tried this ----- SELECT TOP 4 Words1, Words2, Type, ID FROM Table1 WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3 ) AND Type IN (4 ) AND ID NOT IN ( SELECT TOP 12 ID FROM Table1 WHERE Unit IN (1, 2, 3 ) AND Type IN (4 ) ) ORDER BY ID

Comment: It didn't go into catch , but still dont work , what I do worng ?

Comment: @yoad - what do you mean it didn't work? Did it return anything or the wrong thing? Start your query in smaller pieces. Do you know if Unit IN (1,2,3) even does what you want?

Comment: The second part just didn't work (NOT IN)
But you were right, it was something about the ORDER BY , the solution of Gustav solved this. thank you.